# Randomly selecting two (unique) images from a directory

Tags: php, random, unique

I have this code which works well:

```
function random_pic($dir = 'img')
{
    $files = glob($dir . '/*.png');
    $file = array_rand($files);             
}
```

It grabs a random image from a directory. I have this in later:

```
<img src="<?php echo random_pic(); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo random_pic(); ?>"/>
```

Any way I can make it so it they both don't display the same picture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$indexes=array_rand($files,2);
$file1=$files[$indexes[0]];
$file2=$files[$indexes[1]];
```

array_rand can retrieve more then one key, just specify 2 as second parameter. In this case it returns am array.

```
function random_pics($dir = 'img',$howMany=2) {
    $files = glob($dir . '/*.png');
    if($howMany==0) $howMany=count($files); // make 0 mean all files
    $indexes = array_rand($files,$howMany);
    $out=array();
    if(!is_array($indexes)) $indexes=array($indexes); // cover howMany==1
    foreach($indexes as $index) {
        $out[]=$files[$index];
    }
    return $out;
}

$theFiles=random_pics();


<?php echo $theFiles[0]; ?>
<?php echo $theFiles[1]; ?>
```

Comment: Didn't know that one, but it's one of my two solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Can you remember the last one. Then check to see if it was used? if was, get a new one.

```
$one = random_pic();
$two = random_pic();
while($one == $two){
$two = random_pic();
}
```

and in the markup.

```
<img src="<?php echo $one; ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo $two; ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will call the random_pic function sequentially, so you can just return the chosen pic and give it as a parameter to your second call of the function. Then change the function in that way, that the forwarded pic is not chosen.

Answer (score 0):

```
function random_pic($dir_only_imgs, $num) {

    shuffle($dir_only_imgs);
    $imgs = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
        $imgs[] = $dir[$i];
    }
    return $num == 1 ? $imgs[0] : $imgs;
}

$dir = "img"
$dir_only_imgs = glob($dir . '/*.png');

print_r(random_pic($dir_only_imgs, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way looks like:

```
<img src="https://www.example.com/images/image-<?php echo rand(1,7); ?>.jpg">
```

In order to get this to work, you’ll want to name your images: image-1.jpg, image-2.jpg, image-3.jpg,,, image-7.jpg,

When the page loads, the PHP rand() will echo a random number (in this case, a number between 1 and 7), completing the URL and thus displaying the corresponding image.
Source: https://jonbellah.com/load-random-images-with-php/